# Visual Studio Code - How to display variable values inline during debugging?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When I debug Javascript code in VS code or visual studio code, I would like it to show me the values of the variables alongside the code. How to make VS code do that ?

Ideally, don't want to hover my mouse pointer variable over each variable just to see its value, especially if the variable's value occupies only few characters on screen. There are other IDEs whose debuggers show a variables current value next to it.

Example :

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

for(var i = 2; i < 5; i++){  "i : 3"
    array.splice(i,1); "array : {1,2, 4, 5,6,7}"
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Enable `Debug: Inline Values` in your Settings.

1. Open Settings
2. Search for "debug"
3. Navigate to Features > Debug
4. Change the setting for Debug: Inline Values

Options are `on`, `off` or `auto`.

Or change in your `settings.json` file:

```json
{
  // Show variable values inline in editor while debugging.
  "debug.inlineValues": "on",  
}
```

Alternatively, some people use the [Quokka extension](https://quokkajs.com/docs/) for the same purpose.

Comment: Thanks. The debug setting works. There is issue though, the debugger is replacing a big part of my array with three dots. How do I make it display the full array ? The array has only 7, single digit numbers. So, I think that the debugger should not truncate the array.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Hmmm... I'll look around but I am not hopeful.

Comment: I looked through the github issues and could find no mention of it - seems pretty unfortunate.  You could file an issue about it.

Comment: FYI, as of 2022, the value should be `true` rather than `"on"`

Comment: @npit Not sure which setting you were lookng at, `debug.inlineValues` is still `on/off/auto`.

Comment: Perhaps it's just for vscodium then.

Answer (score 6):

Additionally, you could add the VS Code extension called **Quokka**, that allows you to preview some values for the given variable/object, without having to debug.
https://quokkajs.com/whatsnew/?referrer=qsp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32562986)

Comment: +1 for this. I disagree with the negative feedback from the previous comment. You posted the name of the extension and a brief description of the functionality, which gives users enough context to search the plugin if the link doesn't work.